# Referring to this pointer in a static assert?

Tags: c++, boost, this, static-assert

Is it possible to write a static assert referring to the 'this' pointer? I do not have c++11 available, and BOOST_STATIC_ASSERT doesn't work.

```
struct blah
{
   void func() {BOOST_STATIC_ASSERT(sizeof(*this));}
};
```

Produces:

```
error C2355: 'this' : can only be referenced inside non-static member functions
error C2027: use of undefined type 'boost::STATIC_ASSERTION_FAILURE'
```

In MSVC 2008.

Motivation:

```
#define CLASS_USES_SMALL_POOL() \
   void __small_pool_check()     {BOOST_STATIC_ASSERT(sizeof(*this) < SMALL_MALLOC_SIZE;} \
   void* operator new(size_t)    {return SmallMalloc();}                                  \
   void operator delete(void* p) {SmallFree(p);}
```

Comment: I thought sizeof was always compile time? That works for the example, but I am trying to implement the macro without redundantly naming the type, see the Motivation secion.

Comment: Never mind. It's 1:30 AM here. Should not be answering questions at a time like that. You are correct. `*this` has a well defined type.

Comment: `int unused[SMALL_MALLOC_SIZE-sizeof(*this)];`

Comment: Maybe your `__small_pool_check` is actually static. Or you wrote `static CLASS_USES_SMALL_POLL()`...

Comment: @MarcGlisse Nice one!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that `BOOST_STATIC_ASSERT` is a **macro**, it resolves into a C++ construct, in which your `this` keyword has different meaning.

To work this around you may try this:

```
struct blah
{
   void func()
   {
      const size_t mySize = sizeof(*this);
      BOOST_STATIC_ASSERT(mySize);
   }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried your code in [GCC explorere](http://gcc.godbolt.org/), it compiled fine. Not sure why the boost version doesn't work, especially with that error.

```
struct blah
{
  int a, b;
   void func() {static_assert(sizeof(*this) > 4, "big");} // triggers if you remove b.
};

// -Wall -pedantic --std=c++11
```

Comment: BOOST_STATIC_ASSERT seems oddly implemented for MSVC